# City shapefiles from OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

I'm looking to do spatial joins of billions of points to get the city name for each point globally using spark. I'm not able to find a good publicly available shapefile/geojson/kml of city polygons to pull this from.

My current thought is to source this from open street maps. I've already extracted administrative boundaries and all place=city,town using osmosis and imported it into PostGIS. It looks like place=city,town is not populated consistently and there are major cities missing with this tag, so I'm not sure its usable (e.g. [48.860959, 2.352662] is in Paris, but there is no place=city).

So, I'm looking at resorting to using administrative boundaries. The trouble I'm having with administrative boundaries is that different countries define cities at different admin_levels. Even within the US, NYC is admin_level 5 and every other city in the US seems to be 8. Is there a simpler way to pull this or do I have to create a lookup table with an entry for each country that determines what levels the city comes from in preference order? For example:

```
US=5,8
GB=6,8
DE=6,8
FR=8
...
```

If so, does this lookup table of country to admin_level for cities exist anywhere?

Comment: You could reverse geocode through the OSM-based Nominatim service: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim
API reference with info returned: 
https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/

Comment: I appreciate the reference to Nomanatim @DPSSpatial. Unfortunately with billions of requests a day that isn't within their usage limitations. Also, if the latency is even super fast at 10ms it would take 115 days of processing to get through one day of data without flooding their servers. I think having the data in house is the only option. I'll poke around and see if I can figure out how Nomanatim is implemented. Thanks!

Comment: I think you could host it yourself... Otherwise, i don't know if Natural Earth data would work, but they have 'major' urban areas in their admin data

Comment: For Paris there is this [place=city node](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/17807753). Also note that larger cities are usually defined by a boundary (e.g. [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/7444) for Paris). If your requirements don't match with the usage policy of the public Nominatim instances then consider [installing your own Nominatim instance](http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/).

Comment: @scai Thanks for the information on Paris. As for the Paris boundary that you sent, my point is that the place field is not set to city, it is empty for this polygon. Place=city seems to be inconsistently used for major cities. I *think* for all of France I can just look for admin_level = 8 for to get all city boundaries, but this is not the case globally. 

Even if I install Nominatim locally, an api lookup time of 1ms per location would still require 11.5 days of processing for a single day of data, so an api is unacceptable. I think batch joins are the only possible solution.